# Window.print not printing content in new tab, but rather content from previous tab

Tags: javascript, printing

So, I'm opening an image in a modal, and I have a print button underneath that should open up a new tab for the user with JUST the image. I have the window.print command executing after I open up the new tab, but when I try to print, it prints all the previous content from the page before. I need to print JUST the image. I'm not sure if this could be a timing issue, or just a bad way to execute this idea.

my javascript used can be found at on lines 212-263, and a section with a class of product-image is the corresponding markup.

my code can be found at 
http://gdchome.thedesigngrouponline.com/product-category/live/furniture/sofas/

Answer (score 0):

You should call the print function on the page where you display the image. Thus the new tab. Try adding the print function to the onload of that page and it should work.